# ios/xcode XCTest/XCTest.h not found error after adding images

Tags: ios, xcode

I added some images (tab icons) using the finder to the directory for my app, then added them to the project using files-add and finally within images.xcassets, add image set, dragged them over to be used as tab icons.

Somehow in this process, I am now getting a XCTest/XCTest.h not found error.

I don't know if I accidentally clicked on something I should not have or if doing the above created the error.

Can anyone suggest how to fix?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To add test cases to an existing project select the target, right click > file > new > objective c test case class. Then in your build phases you can add the XCTest.Framework. Make sure you check the add to target boxes when creating the test case.